# Where to find information on iOS 8 variable touch sizing API

Tags: ios, ios8

According to MacRumor (http://www.macrumors.com/2014/06/17/pencil-stylus-pressure-ios-8/) the iOS 8 will support variable touch sizing simulating surface pressure. Where can I find its API? I searched Apple Developer iOS Dev Center online library, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Why the down vote??? Perhaps you people can be a little more constructive ?

Comment: +1 this is difficult enough to find to make it worth asking and answering the question and doesn't violate the nda afaik...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS 8 adds two new properties on UITouch: majorRadius and majorRadiusTolerance. They work like this:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    var touch : UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    var lowerBound = touch.majorRadius - touch.majorRadiusTolerance
    var upperBound = touch.majorRadius + touch.majorRadiusTolerance
    var average = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2.0
    println("touch was between \(lowerBound)pt and \(upperBound)pt in size (avg \(average)")
}
```

You can find the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITouch/majorRadius) (need to be logged in since it's pre-release).

Comment: Guess it's not called variable touch sizing. So confusing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the signature to (without optional parameter symbol "!")

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

because XCode Beta 1 throws SpriteKit compiler error. Perhaps it is fixed in Beta 2. (Updated: the bug still exists).